# How to refresh a html ( arduino ethernet webpage ) if a variable is changing?

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, ethernet

I'm a starter in arduino ethernet using and html programing too.
I would refresh the ethernet webpage when an int (value of an integer) is changing.
I know the autorefresh meta. I refresh my webpage in evry 60 sec. I need 60 sec, because iuse some input type, and if i want to fill them, i need 60 sec.
I use buttoms, select, and chechbox inputs, and the buttoms, and other inputs are refresh the page too.
But now, if an integer is change, I immediately need to refresh the page without buttoms, input fields, or links.
How can I realize that?
I think I have to use scripts, something like this:

```
if(x == 1) {                           //x is the integer
  client.println("<myFunction()>");
  client.println("<script>");
  client.println("function myFunction() {");
  client.println("    location.reload();");     //location.reload(true/false); If false, the page will be  reloaded from      
  client.println("}");                              //cache, else from the server.
  client.println("</script>");
  x== 0;
}
```

But the

```
client.println("<myFunction()>");
```

row is not good, and i don't find the solution on the net.

Or html:
I have a variable x, and the question: how start the  myFunction script, if x = 1  ?

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
      location.reload();     
   }
</script>
```

Please help me!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: just do `if (x === 1) location.reload();`

Comment: @Steeve Pitis  I don't understand.
As far as I know HTML don't know variables, only in scripts, or other solutions.

But the question is how can I launch a script in HTML without button, link, select, text box, or other active inputs?

The HTML source will send from a mcu, and the variable is change in the mcu code, not in the HTML code.
I would like to refresh the Webpage, vhen an integer is change in the arduino code. But i can't fint solution. HTML events is generated with buttonc, links, text boxes, or other active inputs.

Comment: You need to create a node server, I guess and handle your changes with websockets.